# Write transformation in typesafe way

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, type-safety

How do I write the below code in typesafe manner in spark scala with Dataset Api:

```
val schema: StructType = Encoders.product[CaseClass].schema
//read json from a file
val readAsDataSet :CaseClass=sparkSession.read.option("mode",mode).schema(schema).json(path)as[CaseClass]

//below code needs to be written in type safe way:
val someDF= readAsDataSet.withColumn("col1",explode(col("col_to_be_exploded")))
      .select(from_unixtime(col("timestamp").divide(1000))
        .as("date"), col("col1"))
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by typesafe way? Spark is kinda not typesafe anyway.

Comment: I mean to say select column with string(col1) but doing with map operation -> ds.map(x=>x.col1.get) is type safe way. We can check errors at compile time but with dataframe it will break at runtime.

Comment: Which part of the code you are showing us would you like to be more typesafe?

Comment: withColumn code and explode

Comment: You can convert to dataset to create a dataset[CaseClass] and then apply the following transformations in a more Scala way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone in the comments said, you can create a `Dataset[CaseClass]` and do your operations on there. Let's set it up:

```
import spark.implicits._

case class MyTest (timestamp: Long, col_explode: Seq[String])

val df = Seq(
  MyTest(1673850366000L, Seq("some", "strings", "here")),
  MyTest(1271850365998L, Seq("pasta", "with", "cream")),
  MyTest(611850366000L, Seq("tasty", "food"))
).toDF("timestamp", "col_explode").as[MyTest]


df.show(false)
+-------------+---------------------+
|timestamp    |col_explode          |
+-------------+---------------------+
|1673850366000|[some, strings, here]|
|1271850365998|[pasta, with, cream] |
|611850366000 |[tasty, food]        |
+-------------+---------------------+
```

Typically, you can do many operations with the `map` function and the Scala language.

A `map` function returns the same amount of elements as the input has. The `explode` function that you're using, however, does not return the same amount of elements. You can implement this behaviour using the `flatMap` function.

So, using the Scala language and the `flatMap` function together, you can do something like this:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZoneOffset

case class Exploded (datetime: String, exploded: String)

val output = df.flatMap{ case MyTest(timestamp, col_explode) =>
  col_explode.map( value => {
      val date = LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(timestamp/1000, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC).toString
      Exploded(date, value)
    }
  )
}

output.show(false)
+-------------------+--------+
|datetime           |exploded|
+-------------------+--------+
|2023-01-16T06:26:06|some    |
|2023-01-16T06:26:06|strings |
|2023-01-16T06:26:06|here    |
|2010-04-21T11:46:05|pasta   |
|2010-04-21T11:46:05|with    |
|2010-04-21T11:46:05|cream   |
|1989-05-22T14:26:06|tasty   |
|1989-05-22T14:26:06|food    |
+-------------------+--------+
```

As you see, we've created a second case class called `Exploded` which we use to type our `output` dataset. Our `output` dataset has the following type: `org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Exploded]` so everything is completely type safe.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please tell how to handle code`df.flatMap{ case MyTest` when MyTest case class have more fields case ;like `case class MyTest (timestamp: Long, col_explode: Seq[String],id:String:Name:String) `,how to exclude other columns?

Comment: I get the error in this case : == Wrong number of arguments for extractor, found: 2,expected 4

Comment: In that case you should define your `MyTest` case class with 4 fields, as you have done, and `Exploded` using 2 fields, and only use the 2 wanted fields inside of the `map` function